# AVAudioSession Interruptions

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession, interruption

So in my app, running on iOS 6, everything seems to work fine with audio.  I use the old C API format to catch interruptions using a callback; setting up via: `AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListenerCallback, (__bridge void *)self)` and it was great.  Using iOS 7 SDK though, it seems that my interruption callback is never called when the device receives calls or an alarm goes off.

After some looking around, I heard that the old C api were deprecated and that you should move to the newer AVAudioSession functions.  More reading revealed that the AVAudioSession delegate is deprecated and that you should use the `NSNotification` for `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` to catch interruptions and do whatever needs to be done.

For me, it seems that this notification is never actually fired and therefore I never get properly interrupted, which then breaks all of my audio stuff after the call ends.

I sign up for the notification like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(AudioInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

For now, the `AudioInterruption:` function simply logs that it got fired.  Neither the log nor any breakpoints are triggering.

To be clear, initially audio playback and recording works fine.  When an interruption occurs (such as an incoming call or an alarm), no interruption notification is fired.  If more surrounding code is necessary, let me know.

Comment: Just as a point, if I manually post the `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` then my observer triggers, so that works.  Still have no idea why the system isn't posting the notification itself.

Comment: Did you set the AVAudioSession mode and called `setActive` ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise audio wouldn't play initially, which it does. `[session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error]` and `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationError]`.  I set the mode before adding the observer, and set active afterward, though it shouldn't matter (?).

Comment: What have you set for your audio categories?

Comment: I use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.  Experimenting with options yielded no changes regardless of choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have an *AVCaptureSession* instance in your application?
If that is the case, I would suggest the same answer that I received for my linked question:
Try to set *NO* to the *[usesApplicationAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/usesApplicationAudioSession)* property of your *AVCaptureSession* instance.
It is a property available since iOS 7. In the previous iOS versions, each *AVCaptureSession* made use of a private *AVAudioSession*. Since iOS 7, the Capture Sessions make use of the shared application's AVAudioSession.
The *[usesApplicationAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/usesApplicationAudioSession)* property is enabled by default, so if you want to keep the old behavior you must disable it, by setting *NO*.

I hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: I'll try it on Monday (or if I get the opportunity over the weekend, I'll run into the office to try it sooner).  Crossing my fingers~

Comment: This fixed my issue!  Thanks so much for the help (and remembering to throw the answer over here after getting your own)!

Comment: what if [I don't have](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24205304/1387438) `AVCaptureSession`? Will this work if I create dummy object of `AVCaptureSession` (without inputs/outputs added)?

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t pass the AVAudioSession instance in your addObserver call as the last parameter.

Try this:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(AudioInterruption:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:session];
```

Comment: Passing the session isn't necessary, it just prevents the observer from picking up notifications from other objects.  Just in case, I edited my code to pass in the session instead of nil, didn't help.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Actually this was the exact reason why I did not receive any notification on iOS 14. Also Apple's documentation states that you should pass a shared instance: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions

Answer (score -1):

For me, activating audio session and adding observer when user actually push play button has resolved the issue; notification was fired. I think apple doc say something about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioGuidelinesByAppType/AudioGuidelinesByAppType.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW1).