# AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification not fired when Video/Camera is used

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, avaudiosession

I have some SIP application. Until I've used audio only evrything was working correctly, I was receiving `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` when it was necessary.

Problem appeared when video was used (receiving and sending camera feed). Once I use session with video, notification is never fired again, even if later audio is used only.

How can I fix that? I've found similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20334467/1387438), but answer is to prompt and I don't fully get it. Also I do not have "camera/capture device" and "AVCaptureSession" since audio and video streaming is provided by closed third party library, but my code have to handle interruptions.

Do I have to change some property to have this notification always fired (linked topic suggest that), or should I use alternative notification.
I was digging in documentation but I've failed to find anything useful for me.

I've tried use dummy object of `AVCaptureSession`, but this didn't solve the problem.

---

**Edit:** Third party library had some additional crashed what exposed that they use `AVCAptureSession`. I've have contact them ask to change property `usesApplicationAudioSession` as described in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20334467/1387438) and "beg" them to fix it. After longer fight they agreed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used category and [method swizzling](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) and it works like charm.

```
#import "AVCaptureSession+MethodSwizzling.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


static void MethodSwizzle(Class c, SEL origSEL, SEL overrideSEL) {
  Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, origSEL);
  Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, overrideSEL);
  if(class_addMethod(c, origSEL, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
    class_replaceMethod(c, overrideSEL, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
  } else {
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
  }
}

@implementation AVCaptureSession (MethodSwizzling)

- (id)initMethodSwizzling {
  self = [self initMethodSwizzling]; // it is not recursion it is method swizzling
  self.usesApplicationAudioSession = NO;
  return self;
}

+ (void)load {
  if (class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setUsesApplicationAudioSession:))) {
    // Swizzle methods only when it is possible to change usesApplicationAudioSession property.
    MethodSwizzle(self, @selector(init), @selector(initMethodSwizzling));
  }
}

@end
```